# JSON to CSV conversion Linux terminal

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv

I have the following example.json. How can I parse it to csv in order to get the mean value (between ** mean_value **).
I want something like in example.csv:

305152,277504,320512

```
    [
{
    "name": "stats",
    "columns": [
        "time",
        "mean"
    ],
    "points": [
        [
            1444038496000,
            **305152**
        ],
        [
            1444038494000,
            **277504**
        ],
        [
            1444038492000,
            **320512**
        ]
    ]
}
     ]
```

Comment: Why "shell command"? Can you use Perl/Python/Ruby or install some json tool?

Comment: yes yes but I don't know which one is better.

Comment: Its not valid json, does it look like this [1444038492000, 320512]?

Comment: The file is generated automatically like that. Yes without  the two **. I put ** Just to show the value I want to retrieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python it looks like this

```
import json

results = []
with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
    content = json.loads(f.read())
    for element in content:
        results.append(','.join([str(y[1]) for y in element['points']]))

with open('example.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(results))
```